# Can't use non standard citation styles with bibtex4word. Why?

Tags: bibtex, citing, msword

Is there anyone around who knows why bibtex4word doesn't know all the citation styles that work in TeXworks (in my case nejm)? I have to use it (sorry) and can't solve it. IEEEtran for example works fine, nejm or numeric results in "Bibtex was unable to find style file: numeric" (or "nejm")

Answer (score 2):

The `bibtex4word` program uses standard `bibtex` to process the bibliography and standard `.bst` files to format it. It is not set up to work with `biblatex`, which does not use `.bst` files for formatting, and generally needs `biber` not `bibtex` for sorting. As a result any style created for use with `biblatex` will not be able to be used with `bibtex4word`.

The `nejm` style is a `biblatex` style, as is the `numeric` style, and so these cannot be used with `bibtex4word`.  There are many numeric standard `.bst` files around, so you may find one that meets your requirements, but it may not match the NEJM style exactly.

See the following question for more details on the difference between the  different bibliography formatting methods.

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693)